# Running PHP on Tomcat 7

Tags: php, tomcat

I am trying to setup PHP on Apache Tomcat 7 using [these notes](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/apache-tomcat-7-0-11-and-php-925305/). I made changes to Web.XML of the web server from my research on the web and it looks like the following:

```
<listener><listener-class>php.java.servlet.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class></listener>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>PhpJavaServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>PhpCGIServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param><param-name>prefer_system_php_exec</param-name><param-value>On</param-value></init-param>
    <init-param><param-name>php_include_java</param-name><param-value>On</param-value></init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>PhpJavaServlet</servlet-name><url-pattern>*.phpjavabridge</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>PhpCGIServlet</servlet-name><url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>
```

Now the Listener entry seem to be preventing the Tomcat7 startup. Below is the data from trace. Has anybody seen or fixed this before? Please share your thoughts.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class php.java.servlet.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:222)
    at php.java.bridge.http.NPChannelFactory.test(NPChannelFactory.java:61)
    at php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionPool.<init>(FCGIConnectionPool.java:175)
    at php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionPool.<init>(FCGIConnectionPool.java:189)
    at php.java.servlet.ContextLoaderListener.createConnectionPool(ContextLoaderListener.java:541)
    at php.java.servlet.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1114)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1673)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
25-mrt-2013 16:38:55 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
25-mrt-2013 16:38:55 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
```

Comment: care to share the reason why you are using Tomcat for PHP?

Comment: @Gordon, I am no PHP/Tomcat expert. I began setting this up yesterday. My primary goal was to write JSPs with Servlets which was achieved. However, my new requirement to communicate with a database seem to be far easier using PHP. So I am following the trend as seen from the web. I am however open to advises.

Comment: If you want to run PHP code, you will be MUCH better off by looking at [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) or [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) on Linux, or [IIS](http://www.iis.net/) on Windows. Tomcat is a server for Java Applications.

Comment: @Srii you can equally well communicate with database with tomcat. Tomcat is a java server, so it's designed to run java code. You should use a server meant for PHP if you want to run PHP. It is possible to run PHP on Tomcat, too, but that won't be what you want if you want an easy way.

Comment: @halfer, Actually many. One such page was [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/apache-tomcat-7-0-11-and-php-925305/)

Comment: I've updated the question for you - updates are usually better edited in, so new readers don't have to read through the comments conversation too.